# publish_post action not as expected

Tags: wordpress

im try to use wp_mail when a post is (created|updated) using the publish_post action

strange thing is it works fine when im editing and existing post, ie all the $post object can be retrieved using:

```
$post = get_post($post_id);
```

but when i use it on a new post it doesnt have the post object???

i can get the vars using the global $_POST but that bloats the code so much, checking if it there or now.

ive tried the other actions as well (save_post|wp_insert_post|publish_post-type)

has anyone ever had this?

Answer (score 0):

You shall add a listener to the publish_post method:

```
add_action('publish_post','do_whatever');

function do_whatever(){
    //what do you do
}
```

OR if you trying to code it in an OO way, you can:

```
include 'MyObj.php';
$my_obj = new MyObj();

add_action('publish_post', array($my_obj, 'do_whatever'));

//in your object php
class MyObj{
   function do_whatever(){
    //what do you do
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** this setup will make the do_whatever call whenever you post is saved/auto saved. you have to do extra coding for your own purpuse.

It will be clear for us to know what are you trying to achieve in order to suggest you more information.